# git find and rename a string in multiple filenames and folder names

Tags: linux, git, unix, grep, find

So Basically I need to find all files and folders in my github project containing the string 'persons'

```
find . -type f -print | grep "persons"
find . -type d -print | grep "persons"
```

The above works for me.

```
But I also need to rename all the above files and folders with 'members'
```

Can I do the above with a couple of commands? Instead of manually replacing them one by one
i dont know how to do a git mv oldfilename newfilename rescursively to the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dir in `find /DIR -type d -iname '*persons*'` ; do
    git mv "${dir}" "${dir/persons/members}"
done
```

Will do. For the files do it with `-type f`.

Comment: can this be used in the context of git?

Comment: it kinda doesnt work . i get a  dquote in my terminal. also i dont need the commit command too

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -depth -name persons |  while read F; do mv $F $(dirname $F)/members; done
```

Comment: That moves only the `persons` files/dirs, not that those that matching the pattern. And skips the git part.